# Problema con fechas en filtro avanzado en celdas de tipo texto

Tags: excel, vba

tengo un extraño problema usando filtro avanzado con el que espero me puedan ayudar.

Como ejemplo, tengo dos tablas dinámicas (una en Hoja1 y otra en Hoja2) con **todas las celdas** en formato **texto**, con lo siguiente en ambas:

```
CODIGO
575/23
100/268
45/20
05/19
4574/89
07/23
04/2021
```

El caso es que siempre que aplico un filtro avanzado de **forma manual** obtengo correctamente todos los datos, pero si grabo el proceso como macro y la asigno un botón, al hacer clic no devuelve los valores '05/19' y '07/23' (por alguna razón los toma como mes y año). Sí devuelve '04/2021'.

Si vuelvo a aplicar el formato de texto a las celdas, en la parte superior izquierda de las celdas de los valores '05/19' y '07/23' se muestra una pequeña marca de color verde y a la derecha un triángulo amarillo, y cuando situó el cursor encima de éste se muestra el mensaje "Esta celda contiene una cadena de fechas representada con sólo 2 dígitos para el año".

El código de la macro:

```
Sub Filtrado()

    Sheets("Hoja3").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    
    Range("los_datos").AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:= Range("el_filtro"), _
        CopyToRange:=Range("el_resultado"), _
        Unique:=False

End Sub
```

Tras hacer clic en el triángulo he probado a omitir el error y otras opciones, pero no logro que se muestren todos los resultados al aplicar el filtro avanzado con el botón (haciéndolo de forma manual sí funciona).

Un saludo !

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Deberías poner el código de la macro

Comment: @Esei Cierto, es sólo el generado al grabar la macro (uso nombres para las tablas y para la celda en la que se pega el resultado).

Comment: Con ese ejemplo sin datos mínimamente verificables tampoco puede sacarse una conclusión. No tengo ni idea de qué tipo de datos es "el resultado", "el filtro" o "los datos" sin ver un ejemplo...

Comment: @dogwall dos tablas dinámicas: una en Hoja1 con nombre "los_datos" y otra en Hoja2 con nombre "el_filtro", mientras que "el_resultado" es el nombre de la celda A1 en Hoja3 (en la que se pegarán las filas obtenidas tras aplicar el filtro avanzado). Luego el tipo de datos de la columna CODIGO es texto (con número variable de dígitos a izquierda y derecha de la barra inclinado).